# Drag And Drop - Div overflow: scroll;

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fullcalendar

Estou usando Drag And Drop dentro de uma div com o CSS: `overflow:scroll`.
Como são muitos dados a barra vertical fica sempre ativa mas ao tentar arrastar os elementos dessa div surge uma barra horizontal e a div aumenta o seu tamanho e o elemento fica invisivel por mais que eu consiga levar ele ao ponto de chegada (no caso o Fullcalendar.io).

Elemento que desejo arrastar:

```
 <span class='fc-event' ID="ooooo" onclick="controle(this)"><%# Eval("Name") %></span>
```

Comment: Tente colocaroverflow-x:hidden no pai onde está a lista dentro. Também verifica se a largura dessa div não está com min-width, provavelmente ela deve precisar de um valor de apenas width ou max-width determinado para não ficar variando essa largura

Comment: Não funcionou.
Ao arrastar a div começa a crescer no sentido que vou arrastando!

Comment: Então deve ser algo no JS e não no CSS. Mas de qq forma o odeiam e vc editar a pergunta com se código !

Comment: Podes criar um exemplo aqui para podermos ver o efeito que referes?